# Stylus renders blank file when --watching

Tags: css, node.js, stylus

I'm just setting up stylus on a simple project and am running this command

```
stylus --watch --compress --out css/ src/styl/
```

and it works fine the first time, and it does realize when I've updated a source file but it saves a blank file in the destination.

Any ideas?

I'm using node v0.6.21 - I've tried with and without --compress if that makes any difference

**EDIT**

I know you can write the commands in various ways, but I don't think it is that.

```
stylus -w src/styl/ -o css/
```

also has the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just tried this on another machine (where I have control over the version of node) using 0.8 and it appears to be fine. Must just be a core node thing.

**EDIT**

Yep, managed to get access to upgrade the original VM to 0.8 and it's all fine